# How do i correct the problem with npm run dev not working

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, vite

(node:12830) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
/home/amaya/Desktop/UM/crm/node_modules/.bin/vite:2
import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.16.0

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this problem and i finally got the correct solution.

This might not work for everybody but it did to me.

**Step 1: Update your vite package**

```
npm update vite
```

**Step 2: Then re-run this command**

```
npm run dev
```

I hope this helps!